# Hover over :nth div, show :nth div

Tags: jquery, loops, hover

I apologize for the title, it's kinda hard to explain though. I have these two divs:

```
<div id="a">
   <div class="categoryBlock"></div>
   <div class="categoryBlock"></div>
   <div class="categoryBlock"></div>
   <div class="categoryBlock"></div>
   <div class="categoryBlock"></div>
</div>

<div id="b">
   <div class="smallDef"></div>
   <div class="smallDef"></div>
   <div class="smallDef"></div>
   <div class="smallDef"></div>
   <div class="smallDef"></div>
</div>
```

If the user hovers over the second div in the first container, the second div in the second container should show. Same for the third, fourth, fifth, ...

I have this code:

```
var CatBlock = $("#content_main-portal-page .categoryBlock"); 
CatBlock.each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            var indexHoverItem = $("#a").find(".categoryBlock").index($(this));
            $("#smallDef").eq(indexHoverItem).stop(true,true).fadeIn(160);
        }, function() {
            var indexHoverItem = $("#a").find(".categoryBlock").index($(this));
            console.log(indexHoverItem);
            $("#smallDef").eq(indexHoverItem).stop(true,true).delay(160).fadeOut(160);
        });
    });
```

Currently, only the first hover works (on the first element), as if there were no each. Could anybody help me?

Comment: can you give us some more code like what is **.categoryBlock** ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm editing it right now.

Comment: Well first in your jQuery you have `#smallDef` yet there are no small defs. There are `.smallDef` if you used ids you'll only get the first element to work as id will only return one element ids must be unique. Also take your indexHoverItem and make it global. Add the listener and when you hover do `smallDef [indexHoverItem].style.display="block";` just some minor errors that I see so far so fix these then go from there.

Comment: EasyBB, i know, i was too fast posting it here. These are classes of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you overcomplicated your function or you wanted something else

```
$('#a div').hover(function () {
    $("#b div").eq($(this).index()).stop(true, true).fadeIn(160);
}, function () {
    $("#b div").stop(true, true).delay(160).fadeOut(160);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, for me this is the most usable function. It indeed shows my method of thinking was overcomplicated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
$('#a > div').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    var m = e.type === 'mouseenter' ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';
    $('#b > div').hide().eq($(this).index()).stop()[m]();
});
```

Comment: is `index()` relative to parent?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Without passing an argument, yes. Otherwise it returns the index of the passed element in the jQuery collection.

Comment: This is nice. I accepted the answer by Spokey because for me it's the best readable.

Comment: What the op also has to think about is what will he do after will they leave this shown div up forever or will it hide after some time or hide automatically after they leave.

Comment: @EasyBB Yes. I had assumed that there will be no visible element on the last `mouseleave` event.

Comment: @undefined I know we both did, but that is why I asked for the ops sake. I like your answers usually as they are the most intelligent.  Though see my answer as to simplify things

Comment: @EasyBB Thank you very much for saying that, that's nice of you. It could be much more readable and maintainable, I was about to delete the answer. I have seen you answer, it assumes that DOM elements have `index` property, but unfortunately the property returns an `undefined` value or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah man I was just waking up when I wrote it haha, just realized it.  oops.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding IDs that indicate the pairing.

```
$("#a").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).attr('tag','b'+i).attr('id','a'+1);
});
$("#b").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).attr('tag','a'+i).attr('id','b'+1);
});
$("#a > div,#b > div").bind('hover',function(){
   $(this).fadeIn();
   $('#'+$(this).attr('tag')).fadeIn();
});
```